# Setting BASE_FORM_ID for custom forms

Tags: 7, forms

Currently I'm working on a custom module (`my_module`) that has some 'submodules' (`my_module_sub`). I would like to alter any of the `my_module_sub_keyword_admin` form using [`hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) to avoid switch statements.

To achieve this I have added the following:

**my_module.module**

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
*/
function my_module_form_my_module_sub_keyword_admin_foo_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Alter any form where BASE_FORM_ID = my_module_sub_keyword_admin_foo
}
```

**my_module_sub_keyword.admin.inc**

(According to the `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter` documentation [the base form ID is *stored* under $form_state['build_info']['base_form_id'].](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) so I *set* it here)

```
/**
* Admin form.
*/
function my_module_sub_keyword_admin($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['build_info']['base_form_id'] = 'my_module_sub_keyword_foo';
}
```

**and it works.**

My question is simple: Is it correct way to set the `BASE_FORM_ID` like the examples above or is there a better/safer solution?